# Prevent updates to NSFetchedResultsController whilst table view is in edit mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using an NSFetchedResultsController with a data source that is updated in the background. This is working really well - as new objects are saved to the managed context they appear in the UITableView. However, this leads to the problem I'm having.

When you swipe to delete a cell, putting the cell into edit mode, if at that point an object is created which pushes the cell down in the table view, the position which the cell occupied will be in edit mode, and not the cell you selected. Basically, the UITableView retains the edit mode on the original index path, without adjusting for the movement of cells.

Is there any way to get around this? Thus far everything I've tried has lead to a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reminds me of a problem i had when reordering uitableview cells.Look at 'Responding to changes' in [NSFetchedResultsController reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It shows a way to temporarily disable the change notification. I used it for reordering, maybe you can get inspiration from it to solve your problem too.

kind regards
y